# MS Access 2016 - Pull client name from separate table in complex query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have three tables for vulnerability scanning jobs: customers, authorization forms, and scans. Relationships are one to many from left to right. I previously had scans directly related to clients, but implemented the forms table to add the ability to prevent scanning without authorization. I have the below query which pulls the dates of the most recent and next coming scans (huge thanks to @donPablo), but when I made the change in tables I'm no longer pulling the correct data from the customers table. I'm not exactly sure how to fix it.

```
SELECT u.Customer_Company, z.*
FROM (Select 
     NZ(a.Scan_Data.Customer_ID, b.Scan_Data.Customer_ID) as Customer,
     aPast as Past,
     aFuture as Future,
     DATEDIFF("d", aPast, aFuture) as Difference  
FROM
    (Select Scan_Data.Customer_ID, Max(Scan_Date) as aPast from Scan_Data where Scan_Date <= DATE() Group By Scan_Data.Customer_ID) a
LEFT JOIN
    (Select Scan_Data.Customer_ID, Min(Scan_Date) as aFuture from Scan_Data where Scan_Date > DATE() Group By Scan_Data.Customer_ID) b
ON a.Scan_Data.Customer_ID = B.Scan_Data.Customer_ID

UNION 

Select 
     NZ(a.Scan_Data.Customer_ID, b.Scan_Data.Customer_ID) as Customer,
     aPast as Past,
     aFuture as Future,
     DATEDIFF("d", aPast, aFuture) as Difference  
FROM
    (Select Scan_Data.Customer_ID, Max(Scan_Date) as aPast from Scan_Data where Scan_Date <= DATE() Group By Scan_Data.Customer_ID) a
RIGHT JOIN
    (Select Scan_Data.Customer_ID, Min(Scan_Date) as aFuture from Scan_Data where Scan_Date > DATE() Group By Scan_Data.Customer_ID) b
ON a.Scan_Data.Customer_ID = B.Scan_Data.Customer_ID

)  AS z LEFT JOIN Customer_Data AS u ON cint(z.Customer) = cint(u.Customer_ID);
```

In this query the Scan_Data.Customer_ID winds up being the FormID and it then pulls the customer's name based on the FormID. I fixed it in my other queries by doing a double inner join to pull the actual CustomerID based on the FormID, but I can't get that to work here because of the existing joins. Form_Data.Customer_ID is the way it's identified in the Form table. All IDs in their primary tables are autonumber generated PKs.

Customer_Data table:

```
.Customer_ID | .Customer_Name | etc.
     1       | Microsoft     |
     2       | Reddit        |
```

Form_Data table:

```
.Form_ID     | .Signature_Date | .Expiration_Date | .Customer_ID
     1       | 01-Jan-19       | 01-Jan-20        | 2/Reddit
     2       | 15-May-18       | 15-May-21        | 1/Microsoft
```

Scan_Data table:

```
.Scan_ID     | .Scan_Title       | .Scan_Date     | .Customer_ID
     1       | First MS 19052018 | 19-May-18      | 1/2/Reddit
     2       | First R 05012019  | 05-Jan-19      | 2/1/Microsoft
```

The above Scan_Data shows the problem I'm having. The numbers in the Scan_Data.Customer_ID field are the PKs from the other two tables. The .Customer_ID field is pulling the customer ID based upon the form ID and not the actual customer ID. It should show like this:

```
.Scan_ID     | .Scan_Title       | .Scan_Date     | .Customer_ID
     1       | First MS 19052018 | 19-May-18      | 2/1/Microsoft
     2       | First R 05012019  | 05-Jan-19      | 1/2/Reddit
```

Comment: Edit question to post sample data as text tables (not images).

Comment: Question has been edited. I hope it's understandable.

Comment: What is a form - a paper document? Why would Scan_Data Customer_ID field have 2 numbers? Exactly what is saved into that field and how is it being entered? Shouldn't this be Form_ID as foreign key? After all, don't you scan documents, not clients?

Comment: Also, why would Form_Data and Scan_Data need to be separate tables? Do they have a 1-to-1 relationship?

Comment: The forms are our authorizations for performing the scans. One company will have many forms and each form will have many scans. One scan will have one form and one company.

Comment: Okay, separate tables but save Form_ID as foreign key in Scan_Data and retrieve Customer info in queries.